# Add elements to Zxing barcode Xaml content page, Xamarin.forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, zxing

I am using Zxing.Net.Mobile.Forms to display a barcode. I'm not sure how to add other elements along with the barcode on one page. I've tried adding it in both c# and xaml but my additional elements do not show. I want to add a label after the barcode and a picture above the barcode.

**Barcode.xaml.cs**

```
public partial class BarCode : ContentPage
    {
        ZXingBarcodeImageView barcode;
        public BarCode()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            barcode = new ZXingBarcodeImageView
            {
                HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand,
                VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand,         
                };

                barcode.BarcodeFormat = ZXing.BarcodeFormat.CODE_128;
                barcode.BarcodeOptions.Width = 300;
                barcode.BarcodeOptions.Height = 150;
                barcode.BarcodeOptions.Margin = 10;
                barcode.BarcodeValue = Helpers.Settings.CardNumber;


                Content = barcode;

            }   
    }
```

**Barcode.xaml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="LoyaltyWorx.BarCode"
             BackgroundImage="NewBg.jpg">
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <StackLayout>
        </StackLayout>
    </ContentPage.Content>


</ContentPage>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are assigning `Content` with `barcode`. Hence, anything in the `XAML` will be overwritten.

You could do this instead. Add the `ZXingBarcodeImageView` to your XAML like:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:zxing="clr-namespace:ZXing.Net.Mobile.Forms;assembly=ZXing.Net.Mobile.Forms"
             x:Class="LoyaltyWorx.BarCode"
             BackgroundImage="NewBg.jpg">
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <StackLayout>
            <zxing:ZXingBarcodeImageView x:Name="Barcode"
                BarcodeFormat="CODE_128"
                HorizontalOptions="Fill" VerticalOptions="Fill"
                WidthRequest="300" HeightRequest="150" Margin="10" />

            <!-- add other stuff here -->
        </StackLayout>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

Then you can remove your code in the constructor so it looks something like:

```cs
public partial class BarCode : ContentPage
{
    public BarCode()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        Barcode.BarcodeValue = Helpers.Settings.CardNumber;
    }   
}
```

Bonus: If you are using the MVVM pattern, you could also bind `BarcodeValue` to a ViewModel and eliminate all the code behind by adding `BarcodeValue="{Binding CardNumber}"` to the `ZXingBarcodeImageView` in the XAML and somewhere setting the Binding Context.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what you want:Showing barcode, an image on the center of it (overlapping), and a label after the barcode

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
                           xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
                           xmlns:zxing="clr-namespace:ZXing.Net.Mobile.Forms;assembly=ZXing.Net.Mobile.Forms"
                           x:Class="LoyaltyWorx.BarCode">
    <ContentPage.Content>
                  <AbsoluteLayout HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">

                    <Image Source="{Binding BarcodeImage}"
                           AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All"
                           AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0, 0, 1, 1"/>

                    <Image Source="{Binding OtherImage}"
                           AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="PositionProportional"
                           AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0.5, 0.5, 100, 100"/>
                  </AbsoluteLayout>

                  <Label Text="MyLabel"/>
      </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```